# Trim Audio Flutter ( ffmpeg_kit_flutter Package) Not Working

Tags: flutter, audio, ffmpeg

Audio Trim is not working

Flutter Version : 3.0.2
Dart : 2.17.3

Package used :
ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^4.5.1

Input file path :
"/data/user/0/com.goonetech.v1.gofinal/cache/file_picker/sample-15s.mp3"

Output file path :
"/data/user/0/com.goonetech.v1.gofinal/app_flutter/output.mp3"

```
double start=2, 
double end=5;

String path="/data/user/0/com.goonetech.v1.gofinal/cache/file_picker/sample-15s.mp3"


    static Future<String> cutAudio(String path, double start, double end) async {
    final Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final outPath = "${dir.path}/output.mp3";
    double start = 1;
    double end = 5;

    try 
{
      await File(outPath).delete();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Delete Error");
    }

    var cmd =
        "-y -i \"$path\" -vn -ss $start -to $end -ar 16k -ac 2 -b:a 96k -acodec libmp3lame $outPath";

    FFmpegKit.executeAsync(cmd, (session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
      print("returnCode $returnCode");
    });

    return outPath;
  }
```

The output is :
returnCode 1

The output path does not have the file (File not found exception)

Comment: Does the input file exist in the given path?

Comment: Yeah.. im playing it in audioPlayer

Comment: I think you have to pass the absolute path and not the relative path. Can you try passing the absolute path to this method

Comment: Yeah, Im passing the path which i have got from filePicker package, where i picked the audio file from gallery

Comment: final logs = await session.getLogs(); add this 
 and print logs

Comment: Output from log : Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable lame for this to work. By default FFmpegKit comes with html package. To use lame you have to use audio library

In android/build.gradle add the ext

```
ext {
      flutterFFmpegPackage  = "audio"
  }
```

Check this for more info https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_ffmpeg/latest/

Comment: after adding the above, " Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame' "