# ffmpeg_kit_flutter operation not permitted for audio operations

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

I'm trying to trim an audio file using `ffmpeg_kit_flutter` but I keep getting the error:

```
audio/path/output.mp3: Operation not permitted.
```

This is the ffmpeg command that I'm using:

```
final cmd="-y -i \"$audioPath\" -ss $audioStartTime -to $audioEndTime -c:a libmp3lame $outPutName";
```

And I've also tried :

```
final cmd="-y -i \"$audioPath\" -ss $audioStartTime -to $audioEndTime -c copy $outPutName";
```

But the error is still the same.
I'm using the `ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl` package.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73002134/trim-audio-flutter-ffmpeg-kit-flutter-package-not-working ?

Comment: @MSalters yes, I've tried adding ext {
      flutterFFmpegPackage  = "audio"
  } to gradle but still getting the error.

Comment: Try setting log level to debug for the ffmpeg package using this https://pub.dev/documentation/ffmpeg_kit_flutter/latest/ffmpeg_kit_config/FFmpegKitConfig/setLogLevel.html and check if you get more info in the logcat. Something about write permissions maybe.

Comment: @mortalis I figured it out. It's a permission problem because my $outputname is based on a custom directory. When I use the default device temporary directory it seems to work.
Problem now is making it work with my custom directory.

Comment: Don't know much about flutter, but in classical android dev I use all files permission to work with any path in my internal storage. Check this one https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files, it requires to show a dialog when app starts to confirm the access to all files. It's what file managers do basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I had set my custom directory to:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myapp
```

Problem was Pictures directory does not allow apps to write audio files to it.
Switching to:`/storage/emulated/0/Music/myapp`
Fixed the problem